# Exchange 2010 Auto-mapping mailboxes feature doesn't work when groups grant permissions

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, powershell, outlook-2010

I have a shared mailbox that I need to deploy to one of our departments in an Exchange 2010 SP2 environment with Outlook 2010 clients.  I'm trying to rely on the [auto-mapping feature introduced by Exchange 2010 SP1](http://www.stevieg.org/2010/08/auto-mapping-shared-mailboxes-in-exchange-2010-sp1-with-outlook-2010/), for obvious reasons, but it's not working.

On closer inspection, [this would be because it doesn't work with groups](http://ibenna.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/automapping-to-a-group/), skillfully preventing it from becoming a useful feature for anyone with more than a handful of mail users to administer.

The above link contains a workaround PowerShell script to read a group's membership and directly add those members to have full access permissions, but this doesn't provide the functionality to update the auto-mapping as people join or leave the department.

Does any one know of a way to get this feature functional when groups are used to grant users full access permissions to a mailbox?  (Or have any ides about how to approach the problem, even?  Right now, I'm thinking of a Powershell script that updates the relevant AD attributes on a regular basis, but... there's gotta be a better way.)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! Glad I could help and let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created this script when we ran into the same issue. Maybe it's not the prettiest thing in the world, but it gets the job done.  I have a separate `OU` for the access groups and then another for the resources mailboxes.  The groups and resource mailboxes use the same name except for an `A-` in front for the group.

e.g.  `A-RESMBX1` for the group name and `REXMBX1` for the resource mailbox.

The script enumerates the groups in the groups `OU` and then the resource mailboxes in that `OU`.  It then cycles through each group and finds the matching resource mailbox.  When a match is found it enumerates the groups' users and then adds them to the `msExchDelegateListLink` attribute of the Resource Mailbox.

It will also remove users from the `msExchDelegateListLink` attribute that are no longer members of the associated access group.  I have this running in a Scheduled Task on a DC.

Our need was due to high turnover of interns that needed to have access to a large number of resource mailboxes.

You'd need to update the LDAP paths to the OUs for `$Groups` & `$ResMBXs` as well as your DC name for `$DomainController`

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$DomainController = "MYDOMAINCONTROLLER"
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Groups,OU=Resource Mailboxes,DC=mydomain,DC=com' -Server $DomainController | Sort-Object Name
$ResMBXs = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Resource Mailboxes,DC=mydomain,DC=com' -Server $DomainController -properties msExchDelegateListLink  | Sort-Object Name

Write-Host "Enumerating Groups and Resource Mailboxes..."
Write-Host ""

# IsMember function is borrowed from : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/5adf9ad0-1abf-4557-85cd-657da1cc7df4
# Hash table of security principals and their security group memberships. 
$GroupList = @{}    

Function IsMember ($ADObject, $GroupName) 
{ 
    # Function to check if $ADObject is a member of security group $GroupName. 

    # Check if security group memberships for this principal have been determined. 
    If ($GroupList.ContainsKey($ADObject.sAMAccountName.ToString() + "\") -eq $False) 
    { 
        # Memberships need to be determined for this principal. Add "pre-Windows 2000" 
        # name to the hash table. 
        $GroupList.Add($ADObject.sAMAccountName.ToString() + "\", $True) 
        # Retrieve tokenGroups attribute of principal, which is operational. 
        $ADObject.psbase.RefreshCache("tokenGroups") 
        $SIDs = $ADObject.psbase.Properties.Item("tokenGroups") 
        # Populate hash table with security group memberships. 
        ForEach ($Value In $SIDs) 
        { 
            $SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Value, 0 
            # Translate into "pre-Windows 2000" name. 
            $Group = $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 
            $GroupList.Add($ADObject.sAMAccountName.ToString() + "\" + $Group.Value.Split("\")[1], $True) 
        } 
    } 
    # Check if $ADObject is a member of $GroupName. 
    If ($GroupList.ContainsKey($ADObject.sAMAccountName.ToString() + "\" + $GroupName)) 
    { 
        Return $True 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
        Return $False 
    } 
} 

Foreach ($gr in $Groups) {

         Foreach ($mbx in $ResMBXs) {
             $MBXName = "A-" + $mbx.Name
             $LDAPUser=[ADSI]"LDAP://$($DomainController)/$($mbx.distinguishedName)"

             if ($gr.Name -eq $MBXName) 
             {
              #Build an Array of DNs from each Group
              $Members = Get-ADGroupMember $gr -Server $DomainController
              if ($Members -ne $Null)
              {
                  Foreach ($mbr in $Members){


                     if($mbr.distinguishedName -ne $Null)
                     {
                        $LDAPUser.msExchDelegateListLink.Add($mbr.distinguishedName)
                        $LDAPUser.SetInfo()
                     }
                    $AddedUsers += $mbr.Name
                  }
              }
              Else {Write-Host -foregroundcolor darkyellow "Group contains no members..."; Write-Host ""}

              if($mbx.msExchDelegateListLink -ne $Null) {
                  $ACLUsers = $mbx.msExchDelegateListLink
                  Foreach ($ACLUser in $ACLUsers)
                  {
                    #Check if user is a member of the current group
                    #If not, remove from attribute
                    $user = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($DomainController)/$($ACLUser)"
                    $userDN = Get-ADUser $ACLUser -Server $DomainController
                    $mem = IsMember $user $gr.Name
                    If ($mem -eq $False)
                        {
                            $LDAPUser.msExchDelegateListLink.Remove($userDN.distinguishedName)
                            $LDAPUser.SetInfo()
                            Write-Host "The Following User was removed from: " -nonewline; Write-Host -foregroundcolor yellow $mbx.Name
                            Write-Host -nonewline -foregroundcolor darkyellow " " $UserDN.Name
                            Write-Host ""
                        }
                  }
                 }
              $Members = ""
              Write-Host "The Following Users were added to: " -nonewline; Write-Host -foregroundcolor yellow $mbx.Name
              Write-Host ""
              Write-Host -foregroundcolor darkyellow $AddedUsers
              Write-Host ""
              $AddedUsers = ""
             }
         }

      }
```

Comment: ***So*** awesome.  That's definitely getting a bounty when it's eligible.

Comment: :) I saw the question and went "HEY I KNOW THAT ONE" haha

Comment: Very nice one! if you need to check the alias column for the mailbox name to match the groupname ($group), you can use the `$mbx.SamAccountName` attribute.